# Any way of recovering ubuntu after purging Python 3?

Tags: python, upgrade, chroot, crash

I used purging for dealing with errors before but had no idea how integral python is for ubuntu's functioning. I tried chrooting and using the commands for fixing broken installs, autoremoving and update/upgrade with no success.

It all started because of a crash during an upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04, the python errors appeared after i tried fixing through chroot

Comment: By the time you get anywhere near correcting this, you could have the system reinstalled. I suggest backing up your data and starting fresh.

Comment: You might want to post the PYTHONPATH for root. The crash might have been a problem with your python path.

Comment: How can i do that? I didn't understand anything while googling "pythonpath"

Answer (score 0):

You can reinstall Ubuntu without losing files. Although you really should back up your files first if possible.

- Make a live cd/usb with a downloaded Ubuntu iso (use startup disk creator
  in activities.)
- Make a note of you user name and password.
- Boot onto usb/cd (change boot order in BIOS/UEFI).
- When you get to the section 'Installation type' choose 'something else'.
- Select '/' as mount point, keep format type and UNTICK format (you'll lose
  data if you format).
- When prompted be sure to use the same user name and password as previously
  noted.
  Continue install and reboot.